# AngularJS ng-bind-html not working

Tags: angularjs, pug, ng-bind-html

I have a jade fragment  that is built though ng-repeat.

```
 fieldset(data-ng-repeat='product in products track by $index')
    input(type='text', ng-model='product.name', name='product.name', placeholder='Enter Product Id')
    button.remove(type="button",ng-show='$last', ng-click='removeChoice()') -
    button.validate(type="button",ng-click='validateProduct($index)') Validate
    p(ng-bind-html="productResponse{{$index}}")
    button.addfields(type="button",ng-click='addNewChoice()') Add fields
```

Here is the angular function that produces the HTML

```
$scope.validateProduct = function (e) {
        //alert($scope.products[e].name);
        $http.get("product?productId="+$scope.products[e].name)
            .then(function(response) {
               $scope['productResponse'+e] = response.data;
            });
```

however the bind is failing.. I can see the html binding correctly if I set a static name i,e replace productResponse{{$index}} with productResponse

Comment: What for is that productResponse function?

Comment: ideally `this['productResponse'+$index]` should work, but if you do `$sce.trustAsHtml` the `text`

Comment: @PankajParkar : Not sure if I understood ..